# API em PHP para utilizar no Xamarin

Tags: php, android, api, ios, xamarin

Estou criando uma API para criar a conexão com o MySQL. Posso utilizar PHP para criar esta API? Posso utilizar normalmente esta API no iOS? Eu vi em muitos lugares ([exemplo](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/528a80/create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-and-mysql/)) que eu posso utilizar essa API para Android, mas não vi ninguém utilizando para iOS.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma API Rest serve justamente para que a aplicação possa se comunicar com o banco de dados em qualquer ambiente cliente, como IOS ou ANDROID.

Dessa forma sua aplicação se comunicara via URL com sua API que pode ser desenvolvida em qualquer linguagem servidor, como PHP ou Ruby.

E você pode integrar qualquer aplicação independente de sua plataforma, desde que ela consiga fazer requisições URL, a única desvantagem é que sua aplicação será dependente de internet para se comunicar com a API.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Rodolfo! Me ajudou bastante a entender!

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente ainda não entendeu o que é cada coisa. PHP você rodará no servidor, não tem nada a ver com iOS ou Android. O seu cliente rodará nesses sistemas operacionais e se comunicará com o servidor via HTTP (provavelmente) e ali estará a tal da API. API REST é universal.

Comment: Era exatamente isso. Não tava entendendo muito bem! Muito obrigado, esclareceu a minha duvida.